# ¿Cómo puedo acceder y modificar los atributos de una clase almacenada en un vector si borre el objeto "original"?

Tags: c++, array

paso a comentar mi problema:
Estoy realizando una aplicación que permite cotizar ropa en una tienda. En mi clase tienda tengo definido un vector de la clase ropa donde debo ir almacenando los distintos tipos de ropa a vender (clases derivadas de ropa como remera y pantalón). Mi problema surge en que no me permite acceder a los objetos almacenados en el vector si he borrado el objeto "original". Por lo que tenia entendido `std::vector` efectuaba un copy constructor y tenia su propio espacio para almacenar datos, por lo que no me queda claro porque no estoy pudiendo acceder y modificar los atributos de los objetos que ya están dentro del vector. Dependiendo las distintas soluciones que intenté, el compilador me fue mostrando distintos errores de acceso de lectura o escritura.
Pd: Si no borro el objeto original (luego de haber ingresado al vector) me funciona bien el código y me permite quitarlo del vector y agregar otro objeto, que este ultimo SI PUEDO ELIMINAR después de ingresarlo al vector.

Store.h

```
#pragma once
#ifndef STORE_H
#define STORE_H
#include <string>
#include <vector>

class Clothes;
class Shirt;
class Pants;

class Store
{
private:
    std::string storeName;
    std::string address;
    std::vector<Clothes*> clothesList;

    Shirt* _shirt;
    Pants* _pants;

public:
    Store();
    ~Store();
    void setClothesPreferences(int clothesType, int alternative1, int alternative2, int quality);
    
};

#endif // !STORE_H
```

Store.cpp

```
#include "Store.h"
#include "Clothes.h"
#include "Shirt.h"
#include "Pants.h"
#include <iostream>

Store::Store()
{
    std::cout << "Please, introduce your store name: ";
    std::getline(std::cin, storeName);
    std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n'); 

    std::cout << "Store address: ";
    std::getline(std::cin, address);
    std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n'); 

    _shirt = new Shirt();
    _pants = new Pants();

    clothesList.push_back(_shirt);
    clothesList.push_back(_pants);

// Si pongo delete _shirt aca, luego me tira error en setClothesPreferences()
}

Store::~Store()
{
    std::cout << "Store closed" << std::endl;
}

void Store::setClothesPreferences(int clothesType, int alternative1, int alternative2, int quality) 
{
    if (clothesType == 1)
    {
        Shirt* _shirt2 = dynamic_cast<Shirt*>(clothesList.front()); // Aca transformo devuelta el objeto almacenado en el vector para volverlo al tipo de dato Shirt
        clothesList.erase(clothesList.begin());

        // SHIRT SPECIFICATIONS FOR FURTHER QUOTE
        if (alternative1 == 1)
            _shirt2->shortSleeve = true;
        else
            _shirt2->shortSleeve = false; // longSleeve

        if (alternative2 == 1)
            _shirt2->mandarinCollar = true;
        else
            _shirt2->mandarinCollar = false; // regularCollar

        if (quality == 1)
            _shirt2->quality; // Standard 
        else
            _shirt2->quality; // Premium

        clothesList.insert(clothesList.begin(), _shirt2);
    }
}
```

Clothes.h

```
#pragma once
#ifndef CLOTHES_H
#define CLOTHES_H
#include <string>

class Clothes
{
public:
    std::string derivedName;
    std::string quality[2];
    double unitPrice;
    int stockAmount;

    Clothes();
    virtual ~Clothes();
};
#endif // !CLOTHES_H
```

Clothes.cpp

```
#include "Clothes.h"

Clothes::Clothes()
{
    derivedName = "Base default";

    quality[0] = "Standard";
    quality[1] = "Premium";

    unitPrice = NULL;
}

Clothes::~Clothes()
{
}
```

Shirt.h

```
#pragma once
#ifndef SHIRT_H
#define SHIRT_H
#include "Clothes.h"

class Shirt : public Clothes
{
public:
    bool shortSleeve;
    bool mandarinCollar;

    Shirt();
    ~Shirt() override;
};

#endif // !SHIRT_H
```

Shirt.cpp

```
#include "Shirt.h"

Shirt::Shirt()
{
    derivedName = "Shirt";
    stockAmount = 2000;
}

Shirt::~Shirt()
{
}
```

Mi idea en realidad es crear un objeto local de la clase Shirt, ingresarlo en el vector y que cuando se termine la función o constructor de Clothes se borre, pero pueda acceder y modificar sus datos desde lo que quedo almacenado en el vector.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Estás en lo cierto. El vector tiene su propio espacio de memoria donde guarda los elementos.

La cuestión es que tienes un vector de punteros:

```
std::vector<Clothes*> ...
```

Por lo tanto lo que se guarda en el vector son direcciones de memoria.

Al usar `delete` sobre cualquier puntero válido estás liberando esa memoria.

---

¿Qué puedes hacer? Depende.

¿Realmente necesitas ubicar cada elemento en una región de memoria diferente a la del vector? Si la respuesta es no, puedes usar un vector que almacene los elementos directamente:

```
std::vector<Clothes> ...
```

Si la respuesta es sí, puedes olvidarte de usar `delete` con punteros inteligentes. La memoria se liberará sola cuando no existan más referencias al objeto de manera similar a como lo hace un lenguaje de código administrado.

Comment: Claro, había visto algo también de punteros inteligentes, pero mi problema es que con la definición del vector como `std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Clothes>>` y al ingresar los objetos de Shirt y Pants también como punteros inteligentes luego no tengo manera de tomar los datos de los atributos y almacenarlos en otra variable local para modificarlos en setClothesPreferences() puesto que al ingresarlos al vector se transforman en objetos de tipo Clothes y no tengo manera de realizar un Type-casting con los punteros inteligentes. Estuve probando pero todavía no llego a otra solución.

Comment: @Pedro no entiendo bien qué es lo que quieres hacer. Seguro lo puedes lograr con punteros normales. Pero respecto a los punteros inteligentes, siempre puedes usar la función [get](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/get) para obtener el puntero normal y hacer la conversión.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda y atención. En base a lo que vos me dijiste me di cuenta mi error en cuanto a como estaba entendiendo las cosas. Yo estaba pensando que en el vector los objetos guardados pasaban a ser de tipo Clothes porque no me dejaba guardarlos en otra variable local que no fuera de ese tipo, pero me di cuenta que, simplemente agregar un metodo virtual en la clase base, las derivadas siguen manteniendo su tipo de dato. Lo probe justo con la funcion `get` que vos me dijiste y efectivamente ejecutan el metodo virtual de las derivadas. Tenia un problema de comprensión.